# Migrating from vue1 to vue2

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to migrate this sample dropdown menu from vue1 to vue2.

http://vuejsexamples.com/vue-dropdown-menu/

I've changed the `ready` method to `mounted`, removed the `json` filter and rewrote the for loop in `close` because it caused errors in the console.

Right now there aren't any errors while I run this, but still, the dropdown doesn't work properly - it does not close when I click outside of the menu.
Can anybody help with migrating this?

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#menu',
  
  mounted: function()
  {
    var self = this
    window.addEventListener('click', function(e){
      if (! e.target.parentNode.classList.contains('menu__link--toggle'))
      {
        self.close()
      }
    }, false)
  },
  
  data: {
    dropDowns: {
      ranking: { open: false}  
    }
  },
  
  methods: {
    toggle: function(dropdownName)
    {
       this.dropDowns[dropdownName].open = !this.dropDowns[dropdownName].open;
    },
    
    close: function()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.dropDowns.length; i++) {
          this.dropDowns[dd].open = false;
        }
    }
  }
  
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 2rem 0;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
}
.menu__item {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 3rem;
}
.menu__link {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.menu__icon {
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.open .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 130px;
  top: 2.2rem;
  display: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.dropdown-menu__item:first-child .dropdown-menu__link {
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}

.dropdown-menu__item:last-child .dropdown-menu__link {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}

.dropdown-menu__link {
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem;
  color: blue;
  background-color: #fafafa;
}
.dropdown-menu__link:hover {
  color: green;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu"class="row">  
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu__item">
        <a class="menu__link" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>

    <li class="menu__item menu__item--dropdown" v-on:click="toggle('ranking')" v-bind:class="{'open' : dropDowns.ranking.open}">
        <a class="menu__link menu__link--toggle" href="#">
            <span>Rangliste</span>
            <i class="menu__icon fa fa-angle-down"></i>
        </a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="dropdown-menu__item">
                <a class="dropdown-menu__link" href="#">Aktuelle Runde</a>
            </li>

            <li class="dropdown-menu__item">
                <a class="dropdown-menu__link" href="#">Siegerliste</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="menu__item">
        <a class="menu__link" href="#">Belegungskalender</a>
    </li>
</ul>
  
  <pre>{{ dropDowns }}</pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this I had to make two changes:

First is in the event listener. When I tested it, I got an exception since `e.target.parentNode.classList` was undefined (when element has no classes). The error is when trying to access function `contains` of `undefined`.

So I made a variable and checked for truthy value on it. If it is undefined, it wouldn't contain the desired class, so you could close the menu.

The next and main problem was this part of the code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.dropDowns.length; i++) {
```

`this.DropDowns` is an `Object`, not an `Array`. Objects don't have length, so you can't use `dropDowns.length`.

Instead, you'd extract the object keys and loop them, then access the values using the key name.

I used `Array.prototype.forEach` instead of the loop for a more functional approach, and this is the final result:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#menu',

  mounted: function() {
    var self = this
    window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      var classList = e.target.parentNode.classList;
      //Check if classList is a valid value. If classList is undefined, contains would throw an error.
      if (!classList || !classList.contains('menu__link--toggle')) {
        self.close()
      }
    }, false)
  },

  data: {
    dropDowns: {
      ranking: {
        open: false
      }
    }
  },

  methods: {
    toggle: function(dropdownName) {
      this.dropDowns[dropdownName].open = !this.dropDowns[dropdownName].open;
    },

    close: function() {
      var dropDowns = this.dropDowns;
      Object.keys(dropDowns).forEach(function(key, index) {
        dropDowns[key].open = false;
      });
    }
  }

})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 2rem 0;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
}

.menu__item {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 3rem;
}

.menu__link {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.menu__icon {
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.open .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 130px;
  top: 2.2rem;
  display: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.dropdown-menu__item:first-child .dropdown-menu__link {
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}

.dropdown-menu__item:last-child .dropdown-menu__link {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}

.dropdown-menu__link {
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem;
  color: blue;
  background-color: #fafafa;
}

.dropdown-menu__link:hover {
  color: green;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu" class="row">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu__item">
      <a class="menu__link" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>

    <li class="menu__item menu__item--dropdown" v-on:click="toggle('ranking')" v-bind:class="{'open' : dropDowns.ranking.open}">
      <a class="menu__link menu__link--toggle" href="#">
        <span>Rangliste</span>
        <i class="menu__icon fa fa-angle-down"></i>
      </a>

      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="dropdown-menu__item">
          <a class="dropdown-menu__link" href="#">Aktuelle Runde</a>
        </li>

        <li class="dropdown-menu__item">
          <a class="dropdown-menu__link" href="#">Siegerliste</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="menu__item">
      <a class="menu__link" href="#">Belegungskalender</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <pre>{{ dropDowns }}</pre>
</div>
```

I'd recommend that you turn this menu into a component. As it is right now, that is non-reusable instance, and you'll surely need to use this dropdown in more places in your project.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I'm trying to get a badge XD